# Mac OS X, make a window go over menu bar

Tags: cocoa, macos, nswindow, menubar

Is it possible to make a window to go over the menu bar, without going in fullscreen?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 17):

Yes, trivially:

```
window.level = NSMainMenuWindowLevel + 1;
```

(Reference: [Drawing to the Full Screen](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_fullscreen/opengl_cgl.html), *OpenGL Programming Guide for Mac OS X*.)

sebastianmarkow is correct in that this is terrible behaviour for a normal document window, but there are several window types for which this is normal: cursors, tool tips, and special utilities like Xscope.

Comment: Still doesn't go over Menu Bar.

Comment: Please clarify. A window with that window level _does_ order on top of the menu bar, but AppKit won’t let you position a titled window overlapping the menu bar (except in some very odd multiple-screen situations). If you want to do this with a document-style window, well, you’re out of luck as far as I know.

Answer (score 4):

I liked Jens Ayton's answer, but rather than pick an arbitrary number like that, I think it would be preferred that you use one of the defined constants.

Personally, I used `NSPopUpMenuWindowLevel` as in:

```
self.window.level = NSPopUpMenuWindowLevel;
```

Other constants that you might prefer, as of my posting this answer, include:

- `NSNormalWindowLevel`
- `NSFloatingWindowLevel`
- `NSSubmenuWindowLevel`
- `NSNormalWindowLevel`
- `NSMainMenuWindowLevel`
- `NSStatusWindowLevel`
- `NSModalPaneWindowLevel`
- `NSPopUpMenuWindowLevel`
- `NSScreenSaverWindowLevel`

Here's the reference (Apple has a tendency to change how they organize their docs and break these links over the years, but the APIs don't change much, which is why I included that list above. I doubt this link will work in 3 years or so, but these constants probably won't change much in the next 20 years.)

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Window_Levels

Comment: Surprisingly, it's been nearly 4 years since I posted this answer and the link still works. Maybe Apple changed their ways and stopped rearranging things and breaking links finally...

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe that you can go on top of the menu bar, but you can set the menu bar to auto-hide when your application is the frontmost application by calling

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] setPresentationOptions: NSApplicationPresentationAutoHideMenuBar];
```

Which should let you use the space normally used for the menu bar in your application.

Comment: From docs: "If you specify `NSApplicationPresentationAutoHideMenuBar`, it must be accompanied by either `NSApplicationPresentationHideDock` or `NSApplicationPresentationAutoHideDock`."  Otherwise an exception is raised.