# Setting Window Level Swift Error OSX

Tags: macos, swift, window

When trying to set window level in `swift` im getting `Use of unresolved identifier 'window'` error using:

`window.level = Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(Int32(kCGScreenSaverWindowLevelKey)))`

or

`window.level = NSScreenSaverWindowLevel`

Ive Checked 
here  [How to set window level in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168257/how-to-set-window-level-in-swift)

Here  [Mac OS X, make a window go over menu bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772515/mac-os-x-make-a-window-go-over-menu-bar)

Here  [NSWindow Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Window_Levels)

I cant seem to access `NSViewController` or `NSWindowController` window property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subclass `NSWindowController`

in `windowDidLoad()`

`window?.level =  Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(Int32(kCGScreenSaverWindowLevelKey)))`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396957/keep-window-always-on-top-cocoa-swift/27397096#27397096

Answer (score 10):

Update for Swift 2:

```
panel.level = Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(CGWindowLevelKey.PopUpMenuWindowLevelKey))
```

Answer (score 4):

Update for Swift 3:

```
window.level = Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(CGWindowLevelKey.popUpMenuWindow))
```

Comment: Thank you for translating the solution to Swift 3! :)

Comment: Should be:  `window?.level = Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(CGWindowLevelKey.popUpMenuWindow))`